# Best alternative in swift to push notifications to communicate server with app in intranet

Tags: swift, push-notification, communication

I have and app working in an intranet, so I can't use push notifications.
My app is working asking to a webservice every second about some data, but the cost of the battery is so expensive and the iPad is runing out of battery very fast.
I need ideas to communicate with my server with a low cost of battery and without push notifications.
I can use solutions not allowed by the rules of the App Store because this is an Enterprise App.
Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: I feel like the alternative is to use sockets... <https://www.raywenderlich.com/537-real-time-communication-with-streams-tutorial-for-ios>. I don't really know what your use case is but if you are making a rest request every second to poll for some data then switching to a socket based framework would probably help.

Comment: Thank you Sam, I will take a look to this option to test the battery consumption.